# Перевод формата .ui в .py

Tags: python, qt

У меня установлен python версии 3.4 (в path пути прописаны) и pyqt5.
Путь к питон:

> C:\Python34

PyQt5 стоит тут:

> C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5
>   В path пути имеются

При форматировании формы из qt designer в формат `.py` получаю такую ошибку:

```
C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4>pyuic5.bat form.ui -o form.py
```

> ""C:\Python34\python"" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Подскажите что я не так делаю?

Comment: Попробуй запустить python из коммандной строки C:\Python34\python
Похоже у тебя где-то напутано с путями

Comment: C:\Python34\python C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\pyuic.py form.ui -o form.py